# I can't make multitle select box work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't seem to make this [plugin](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/select2-latest.html) to work properly. The documentation is a bit confusing.

Here's the site I'm working on "http://smartbin.launchlabs.asia/" and here's a jsfiddle jsfiddle.net/7Ljq2/ of my code.

```
<select multiple id = "zipcode" style = "height:auto;">
<optgroup label="Brighton Council">
    <option value = "BC">Brighton 3186</option>
    <option value = "BC">Brighton East 3187</option>
    <option value = "BC">East Brighton 3187</option>
    <option value = "BC">East Hampton 3188</option>
    <option value = "BC">Hampton 3188</option>
    <option value = "BC">Hampton East 3188</option>
    <option value = "BC">Highett 3190</option>
    <option value = "BC">Sandringham 3191</option>
    <option value = "BC">Beaumaris 3193</option>
    <option value = "BC">Cheltenham 3192</option>
    <option value = "BC">Black Rock 3193</option>
    <option value = "BC">Mentone 3194</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

This is inside the head tag

```
      <link href="/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="/select2.js"></script>

  <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

          $("#zipcode").select2(); 

        });
  </script>
```

I might just missed something really obvious.
I really need help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your [site](http://smartbin.launchlabs.asia/) has some error:

```
  jQuery.document).ready(function() {
      alert("hi");
    jQuery("#zipcode").select2();

    });
```

there is not bracket `(`:

you must use : `jQuery(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: Thanks sir, Had it working when I saw that I was using $ instead of jQuery.

Comment: @RichardSon for javascript debbuggin you can use firebug or chorme console

Answer (score 2):

I've updated your jsfiddle example with the issues that I saw.

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7Ljq2/1/

A few things:

- You have to include the the external resources (JS, CSS).
- You have to include jQuery, since it's required by the plugin you're using.
- The JS code should ran `onDomReady` instead of `onLoad`.
- The select doesn't need the `style` or `multiple` attributes.

Most of the options are configured in the left-hand menu of the jsfiddle interface.

**HTML**:

```
<select id="zipcode">
    <option value = "BC">Brighton 3186</option>
    <option value = "BC">Brighton East 3187</option>
    <option value = "BC">East Brighton 3187</option>
    <option value = "BC">East Hampton 3188</option>
    <option value = "BC">Hampton 3188</option>
    <option value = "BC">Hampton East 3188</option>
    <option value = "BC">Highett 3190</option>
    <option value = "BC">Sandringham 3191</option>
    <option value = "BC">Beaumaris 3193</option>
    <option value = "BC">Cheltenham 3192</option>
    <option value = "BC">Black Rock 3193</option>
    <option value = "BC">Mentone 3194</option>
</select>
```

**JS**:

```
$("#zipcode").select2();
```

Answer (score -1):

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

here you can get nos of types of select boxes.Try and check your code with the ones.